# How do you show that a spell is prepared in Fantasy Grounds?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, fantasy-grounds

Fantasy grounds has the column header 'Preparation', but how can you display whether a spell is prepared or not? Do you use the 'use column'?
[image: Screenshot of Fantasy Grounds' character sheet UI]

Comment: Your intent really isn't clear and still isn't. I still hope that you'll clarify this question further, because we really had to guess at what you were trying to say.

Comment: Deleting noise not relevant

Comment: By 'use column', do you mean the uses per day column?

Comment: Correct - Should I use it to say it is prepared if I have >0 uses

Comment: http://www.fantasygrounds.com/forums/showthread.php?21483-Spellcasting-and-the-powers-tab-of-the-character-sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply update to the most recent version of the 5e module in Fantasy grounds, there are check boxes on the left side of each spell on the actions tab. You keep track of how many spell slots you have on the top.

TLDR; Top is spell slots, check boxes are prepared spells.

Comment: And once prepared you can click "Preparation" to move into combat mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried to add the spells as powers, not as spells.

If you click the button on the lower right,  there should be two options available 'add Spell' and 'add Power'.

Powers are something like Rage or Bardic Inspiration,  which can only be used x number of times between two rests.

If you add the spells as spells you can change the button on the lower left to 'Preparation', then you can see checkboxes next to the spells. If you check them, and change the button back to 'Standard' or 'Combat' you should be able to see a little icon next to the spells prepared.

At least all of this should work in the latest version of the ruleset.